# How to transform $\log_bf(n)<\log_b \sqrt{g(n)}$ into $f(n) < \sqrt{g(n)}$?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I need to transition from $\log_bf(n)<\log_b \sqrt{g(n)}$ to $f(n) < \sqrt{g(n)}$. I understand that I need an inverse of $\log$ but I can't find the proper function for this situation.

Comment: What do you think of $x\to b^x$ ?

Comment: @Max that'd work but as far as I understand it's not really function?

Comment: What do you mean, "not really a function"? If you put $h(x) := b^x$ ( $b >1$) then $h$ is a function, and more importantly here, a strictly increasing one

Comment: @Max I guess you're right, I thought there was a well known function for that like $\tan$ and $\arctan$ for example. So I should just use $h(\log_b(f(n))$?

Comment: Yes, and if $b>1$ the inequality will be preserved